# Hbase restore table from snapshot after the table is truncated

Tags: hbase

I executed below statement in order :

```
hbase> snapshot 'table1', 'snap_table1'
hbase> disable 'table1'
hbase> truncate 'table1'
hbase> restore_snapshot 'snap_table1'
```

```
hbase> scan 'table1'
```

And when i scan table1,
I got 0 row(s) (basically it had 108,415,618 rows)

what happened to the 'snap_table1' and 'table1'?
In addition, I executed below.
table2 is succeeded to restore with snap_table1

```
hbase> clone_snapshot 'snap_table1' , 'table2'
```

I am new to Hbase and learning it day by day.
Can you give me resources about detail of snapshot for study?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try something like this:

```
snapshot 'TableName', 'SnapshotName'
```

.... delete old / create new / or truncate the table, and then:

```
clone_snapshot 'SnapshotName', 'TableName'
```

Also, keep in mind, that if you use just the `truncate` command, the table region split structure will be destroyed (i.e. the empty table will have just one new region). If you want to preserve the old region structure, use `truncate_preserve` instead. If you want to experiment with these options, use the describe command to see the difference in the resultant tables.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the table 'table1' instead of Truncate it.
And restore_snapshot it from 'snap_table1'
It works for me.

```
hbase> disable 'table1'
hbase> drop 'table1'
hbase> restore_snapshot 'snap_table1'
```

I don't know the secret of truncate operation.
But I guess it is same result.